# Custom MySQL Connector for Power BI using power query

Tags: mysql, powerbi, powerquery, connector, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to create a custom mysql connector for power BI that only selects from a single table.
I tried using the

`MySQL.Databast("localhost","mydatabase",[Query = "select * from mytable"])`

but every time i try to connect on power BI i get the error below

[image]

Can anyone please help me out?

The reason I want the connector in such a way that it just shows my users the records in the table.

Comment: why don't you create mysql user who only has connect and select permission to that specific table?

Comment: because i didn't want them to go through the process of entering the server, database, username and password

Comment: I just want them to click in the connector and get data directly from the table.